# Why HashSet sometimes doesn't add object when relying on default hash and equals?

Tags: java, equals, hashset, hashcode

I am working with a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashSet<MyClass>>` and sometimes when adding a newed up MyClass to the set, it will fail. The constructor takes 3 parameters, 2 of which are the same instance but 1 parameter is different in instance and value. During batch runs of 500 test executions I've seen failure rates from .5% - 18% when using the default hash and equals methods provided by Java's Object. However when I generate them myself or use Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` to create them for me, in over 250k+ tests I have never seen it fail. I dove into what's happening underneath and could not find a solid answer as to why sometimes `HashSet#add` will return false, ie not add the object to the set even though MyClass is being called via new constructor.

Some possible theories I've seen:

- HashMap will use a modulus against the size of the underlying container to determine where to place it. This could create a conflict if the keys are different but I don't see any instances of HashMap using a modulus operator.
- HashMap will use the hashCode plus its own hashing function to determine the hash of a key. Since the default hashCode may not always return the same hash, it could cause unstable results when called again in HashMap's hashing function. This one I'm more inclined to believe since when overriding the hashCode function provides a stable result.

However, I have not yet found the definitive answer as to why when using the default hashCode and equals functions from Object, does `HashSet#add` sometimes return false when adding Objects that contain different fields and are unique instances created via new constructor?

```
public class MyClass extends MyHelperClass {
    private String myString;

    public MyClass(String id, String id2) {
        super(id2);
        this.myString = id;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyHelperClass {
   private String myString;

    MyHelperClass(String myString_){
        this.myString = myString_;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MyHelperClass that = (MyHelperClass) o;
        return Objects.equals(myString, that.myString);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(myString);
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeService {    
public final Map<String, Set<MyClass>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void addThis(String id1, String id2) {
        myMap.computeIfAbsent(id1, a -> new HashSet<>());
        myMap.get(id1).add(new MyClass(id2, id1));
    }
}
```

Test I'm runing:

```
    SomeService someService = new SomeService();

    void test() {
        someService.addThis("id1", "id2");
        someService.addThis("id1", "id3");
        assertThat(someService.myMap.get("id1").size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
```

In typing this out I realize that the class I'm extending has Lombok generated hash and equals but the class that's inheriting does not have the methods. When I add equals and hash on the inheriting class all is peachy. Still not 100% positive on why the HashSet doesn't like it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: What exactly fails? The `map.put` or the `set.add()`? If the latter, why does the HashMap matter for the question since the string key should be all that is being compared?

Comment: There is a third option: your code is doing something wrong, or there is a wrong assumption in it. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Both of those 2 theories can be checked *by reading the Java source code*.  They will be easy to disprove.

Comment: @OneCricketeer if you look under the hood, a HashSet uses a HashMap. HashSet#add takes an E. That is fed to HashMap#put as the key and the value that's pased is a a static final Object from the HashSet class called PRESENT.

Comment: @StephenC that is 100% correct. That's a lot of Java source code to look through. And some of it isn't even defined in Java. Object#hashCode for one.

Comment: The obvious next step is that **when** your test case fails to insert, **then** you dump out the object you're trying to add, and the one that's in the set, and the hashCode of both, and the result of comparing them, both via `equals()` and via `==`.

Comment: 1) There is not a lot to look through.  The source code of ConcurrentHashMap etc are only a few thousand lines long.  2)  The native code can be read as well.  I read it ... regularly.  But my real point is that those theories *could* be easily proved or disproved.  When someone posts a theory that a fundamental aspect of Java (e.g. that `Object::hashCode` can violate the equals/hashCode contract), then the onus is on >them< to provide real evidence.  (Java is not US politics ...)

Comment: @StephenC As a new programmer it's always nice to get answers from those who have experience, which is why crowdsourced answers are great. Love that you read Java source code, you must have some answers then. I'm not submitting any theories about Java. I've stated those above are some that I've run in to from years ago and have come here to get answer from people like you, who have read the source code.

Comment: Well.  I think that the experienced programmers here have already given you the answer you need.  *"There is a third option: your code is doing something wrong, or there is a wrong assumption in it. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".*   And don't waste your time on theories ... posted without any supporting evidence.

Comment: @StephenC for sure. Updated with minimal reproducible example. Not sure why we're still talking about theories <.>

Comment: I modified your code to make it compile ... and I cannot reproduce the effect that you claim.  Please provide your **complete** minimal reproducible example so that we can reproduce the behavior you are seeing.  (Could it be that `TASK_ID1` is not equal to `"id1"`)?

Comment: I am willing to accept that this might be some weird Lombok-related issue (but you asked this as a Java question ...).  However, it is more likely that what you see (and I don't see!) is actually due to some bug or incorrect assumption in your actual code ... that is not manifested in the code snippets you showed us.

Comment: @StephenC it would help to know what you had to modify in order to make it compile. I can update the service class to be properly declared and roll my own hash/equals code so the fear of Lombok muddling a Java question is taken care of. Outside of that, telling me what you had to do would help me and other people know how it was ***incomplete***.

Comment: You are expected to post working code here, and if it doesn't compile it is up to you to fix it.  As for "I'm not submitting any theories about Java. I've stated those above are some that I've run in to from years ago", this is just a self-contradiction. When you encounter unexpected behaviour it is 99.999% certain that the problem is your code rather than the programming language implementation, the operating system, etc. They've already been tested millions of times before you even wrote your code, which by contrast has never passed a test at all.

Comment: @JoshuaM. `MyHelperClass` defines a custom equals/hashCode implementation which only compares a single string field. This is contradictory to "the default implementation provided by Java does not work". The default implementation is never used in the code that you have shown

Comment: `HashSet` uses `equals()` and `hashCode()` to detect equality of two objects. Since the class `MyClass` doesn't implement them due to inheritance the methods from the superclass `MyHelperClass` are used.

Comment: @user207421 Not trying to contradict myself. I was trying to show that I have done some looking into what I could have been doing wrong but people have took that to mean I am baking up new theories about the way Java works. I figured with some experience floating around here, I'm not the first person to screw up my code in such a manner.

Comment: To make the code compile it was necessary to add some imports (IMHO of minor importance) and then your test code accesses some field `lockService` which is never declared - but from the test logic it I think you meant to use the field `someService`

Comment: @JoshuaM - Things like ... adding a `package`, adding imports, putting a class around the "test" code, and putting the code in a "main" method.  Stuff that is obviously NECESSARY to make a proper minimal reproducible example ... that can be COMPILED.  Please read the link that explains what minimal reproducible example is supposed to be.

Comment: Here's the thing though.  I don't think you will succeed in creating a minimal reproducible example ... i.e. one that actually reproduces the problem.  Why?  Because I strongly suspect that what you are seeing is caused by something else.

Comment: But ... maybe ... consider this.  What you have in the snippets is a `ConcurrentHashMap` where the values are `HashSet` instances.  If in your actual code (or tests) you are calling `addThis` from multiple threads ... then you have a thread-safety issue.  It looks like there could be multiple threads updating the same `HashSet` without proper synchronization.  (Can I be sure of this?  No!  I could only be sure if I could see your real code or a proper minimal reproducible example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SomeService` class from your test code will generate in the end the following objects:

```
new MyClass("id2", "id1");
new MyClass("id3", "id1");
```

Due to inheritance the following base constructor will be called for these two objects:

```
new MyHelperClass("id1");
new MyHelperClass("id1");
```

As you see, you call your base constructor with the same argument. And based on your `equals()` implementation they are the same (and have the same hash code). Check the following example code to show the issue:

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass("id2", "id1");
MyClass o2 = new MyClass("id3", "id1");
System.out.println(o1.hashCode());
System.out.println(o2.hashCode());
System.out.println(o1.equals(o2));
```

This will generate the following output:

```
104085
104085
true
```

And as they are equal only once instance will be saved in your `HashSet()`.